# How to find number of "Multiplying Functions"?

Tags: functions, contest-math

> Consider the set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. We call the function $f$
> "Multiplying" if for each $x,y\in A$, at least one of these two
> conditions satisfied:
>
> - $x\times y>5$
> - $f(x\times y)=f(x)\times f(y)$ How many Multiplying  $f$ from $A$ to $A$ exist?
>
> $1)25\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad2)1\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad3)50\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad4)60\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad5)55\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$

For the $x\times y>5$ we have these pairs: $$(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4),(4,5),(5,2),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5)$$So I can choose three pairs starting with $2$ and four pairs starting with $3$ or $4$ or $5$ . I need also one pair starts with $1$ (because functions from $A$ should contain all the elements of $A$ for its domain) . I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Are we supposed to think $f:A \to A$ so $f(2)=0$ is prohibited?

Comment: @Henry Yes I  think it is prohibited.

Comment: Right.  So $f(2) = f(1\times2) = f(1)\times f(2)$ iff $f(1) = 1$.  Then do $f(1 \times 3), f(1\times 4), f(1 \times 5), f(2 \times 2)$.  Finally, don't forget $f(1 \times 1)$.

Comment: @GEdgar I got $f(1)=1. For other prime numbers second condition doesn't help. But we can have $f(4)=f(2)f(2)$ so from $1$ we have one possible mapping for $2$ three possibility and for $3,4,5$ four possibilities. So number of functions should be $3\times4^3$ but we don't have it in the choices. ( I think we can't use $f(4)=f(2)f(2)$ because $f(2)$ should be three at least.

Comment: $f(4) = f(2)^2$, so $f(4)$ is a perfect square.  Only two choices for $f(4)$.  Given $f(4)$, there is only one choice for $f(2)$...